# If $u_n \to u$ in $C([0,T];H^{-1})$ and $\lVert u_n\rVert_{L^\infty} \leq C$ then $u_n(t) \rightharpoonup u(t)$ in $L^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u_n \to u$ strongly in $C([0,T];H^{-1}(\Omega))$ and suppose that $u_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega)$. Then
$$u_n(t) \to u(t)$$
weakly in $L^1(\Omega)$ for each $t$?

Can someone show me what result this is? How it is gotten?

Comment: I have no idea. We must have $u_n(t) \to u(t)$ in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ for each $t$ but other than that I do not know. We also have $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $L^1(0,T;L^1)$. But I don't think this implies the result i wanted because $u(t)$ as a function of $L^1$ is only defined a.e.

Comment: @riem equi-integrable (in the paper), or uniformly integrable.. see below

Comment: Thanks @AthanagorWurlitzer. Can you explain why $\lVert u_n(t) \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C$ follows from assumptions? Does one not need $\lVert u_n \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)} \leq C$ for this?

Also I posted this question on MO where Terrence Tao wrote it folows from uniform boundedness principle but I didn't fully follow it. You may be interested: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172942/b-n-rightharpoonup-b-in-lqq-forall-q-infty-b-n-to-b-in-c00-t

Answer (score 1):

I think you need $\Omega$ of bounded measure (e.g. bounded).

Fix $t\in[0,T]$. You have $u_n(t)\to u(t)$ in $H^{-1}$.
Furthermore, $\sup_n \|u_n(t)\|_\infty=M<\infty$ by assumption.

Therefore your sequence $u_n$ is *uniformly integrable*, which means,
that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all measurable set $A\subset\Omega$, if $|A|<\delta$ then $\int_A|u_n| <\epsilon$, for all $n$.

This is the case here: 
$$
\int_A |u_n|\leq \sup_n \|u_n\|_\infty |A|,
$$
so $\delta=\epsilon/(M+1)$ works.

This is a particular case of a more general result, namely that if the sequence is $u_n$ is bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$, uniformly integrable, and $\Omega$ has finite Lebesgue measure, then  you can extract a weakly converging subsequence $\tilde{u}_n$ in $L^1$. This is proved here [in these lecture notes](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~chou/notes/functional.pdf) for example, page 37 (prop 80).

By uniqueness of the weak limit, you then get rid of the subsequence (as $u_n(t)\to u(t)$ globally in $H^{-1}$).

Comment: Also, isn't this true for a.e. $t$ only? Since we only have $u_n$ bounded in $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)$.